# google analytics under pypi doc page (packages.python.org)

Tags: python, google-analytics, pypi

I'm trying to add a google analytics tracker to the documentation pages of my python project (hosted under http://packages.python.org/myProject). Doc pages are generated using sphinx.

I have tried Single Domain and MultiDomain options for the tracker, but Google Analytics seem not to detect the script (which, I have tested, is correctly inserted in all the pages including index.html).

Is there any known limitation that prevents me from using Analytics, Sphinx and PyPI documentation hosting?

thanks!

Comment: Google Analytics's "Script Detection" is only a courtesy feature; it's not the canonical way to determine if your Google Analytics is tracking. The easiest way is to check for today's data, or to inspect HTTP requests. Can you provide the link to your package?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the [`_setCookiePath`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#singleSubDirectory) option.

In particular, if your app is at `http://packages.python.org/myProject/`:

- add `_gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/myProject/']);` into your snippet, right before `_gaq.push(['_trackPageViews']);`.
- Also, under the "new" (as of 10/2011) analytics interface, I think you have to change the web property's default url to read `http://packages.python.org/myProject/`, not just the domain name.
- Note the trailing `/` after `myProject` in the above steps.

There does currently seem to be a bug with the new interface, it showed the tracker as "not enabled" for me, but when I did all the above and switched back to the "old" interface, it showed the tracker as active, and I seem to be getting data when people check my library's python manual.

Comment: `_setCookiePath` is only to avoid having othDo you have documentation to support your claim about the property's default URL?

Comment: @yahelc: the documentation I linked to says [\_setCookiePath](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#singleSubDirectory) should be used when "You have access only to a sub-directory of a larger website", such as the case here. [This](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCookiePath) is a link to some more documentation about _setCookiePath, which repeats that, but also mentions that a trailing "/" is recommended.

Comment: @yahelc: Annoyingly, I cannot find the documentation mentioning that profile's default url had to be set; but the Google Projects help text for setting up GA does say the profile's url has to be `code.google.com/p/myproject/`, though that might be a google code requirement, and not general for GA. (I can't figure out how to make a link to that help text, or I would)